# I have been following to try and write a powershell script to add a new group of local user to windows

Tags: powershell

$user | ForEach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $*.Display name -FirstName $*.First name -LastName $*.Last name -UserprincipalName $*.User principal name -LicenseAssignment $*.Licenses -password WXAqa@123 -Office $*.officeaddresss -MobilePhone $_.Phone number -UsageLocation "IN"}

it shows this kind of ERROR:
New-MsolUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'name'.
At line:1 char:18

- ... | ForEach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $*.Display name -FirstName $*.F ...
- 
- CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.NewUser

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the variable names cannot include spaces. I am not sure about the dot at the start as well

Try using

```
$Display_name
```

Instead of

```
$.Display name
```

Similarly with all other variables of course.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but shows another error

Comment: New-MsolUser : You must provide a required property: Parameter name: UserPrincipalName
At line:1 char:18
+ ... | forEach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $Display_name -FirstName $First ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [New-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.RequiredPropertyNotSetException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.NewUser

Comment: Maybe the typo "UserprincipalName" instead of "UserPrincipalName"